# Receive notifications from characteristic

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm learning android ble api. I can't receive notification from a characteristic that it's protperty is 0x002. So I tried `setCharacteristicNotification(mChar, true)` and `descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE)` to make onCharacteristicChanged invoked. But it does't work, can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [0x02 (Click here to see all the available properties)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#PROPERTY_BROADCAST) means that you can only read this characteristic and you cannot enable notifications to it.

To read a characteristic value use the following method:

> [mBluetoothGatt.ReadCharacteristic(mChar);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#readCharacteristic(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic))

and then the

> [onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic
>   characteristic, int status)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20int))

callback will be called with the updated value of the characteristic. You can then use one or more of the following methods to retrieve it's updated value

> [ch.getFloatValue(formatType, offset);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getFloatValue(int,%20int))
>   
> [ch.getIntValue(formatType, offset);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getIntValue(int,%20int))
>   
> [ch.getStringValue(offset);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getStringValue(int)) 
> [ch.getValue();](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getValue())